# What's the type of iChannel[0-3] in Shadertoy?

Tags: glsl

I'd like to have a helper function in the Common tab that does something fancy with texture input and returns the result. I'd like the function in question to be able to use any `iChannel`, like:

```
vec3 do_something_fancy( in channelType channel, in vec2 uv, yodeling monkey_nuggets) {
    vec4 lookup_result = texture(channel, uv);

    ...
}
```

I've taken a few guesses as to the type of `iChannel[0-4]` but have struck out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Google was useless for answering this one, but I was surprised that Bard got it on the first go:

```
vec3 do_something_fancy( in sample2D channel, in vec2 uv, yodeling monkey_nuggets) {
    vec4 lookup_result = texture(channel, uv);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can click 'Shader inputs' above the panel containing the code to obtain a dropdown with all the types:

[image]

As can be seen here the type is either sampler2D or samplerCube.

Comment: I'd never noticed that before. Nice!